# Siteminder - custom authentication using an xml request.

Tags: xml-parsing, siteminder, custom-authentication

I have an xml request containing username and password which has to authenticated by siteminder. Due siteminder's limitations of doing so, can i parse the xml and post to login.fcc and proceed. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the authentication webservices offered as part of SPS now.. Both SOAP and REST interfaces are available and you will not have to mess with the login.fcc

Hope this helps